# Extract Unicode text in python

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I have OCR detected text as ¾,½,¼,etc. I am trying to seperate the value as 3 and 4 in ¾. ¾ was read as unicode. While converting to string, the exact value was changing with unwanted characters. Kindly suggest a way to resolve this.

Comment: Show us sample code with some input and output which you tried

Answer (score 1):

Utilize [Unicode Normalization Forms](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) as follows:

```
import unicodedata
print('NFKD')
print(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', '¾,½,¼'))                  # Fraction Slash
print(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', '¾,½,¼').replace('⁄','/')) # Solidus
print('NFKC')
print(unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', '¾,½,¼'))
print(unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', '¾,½,¼').replace('⁄','/'))
```

Output: `.\SO\67189705.py`

```
NFKD
3⁄4,1⁄2,1⁄4
3/4,1/2,1/4
NFKC
3⁄4,1⁄2,1⁄4
3/4,1/2,1/4
```

[Table 1. Normalization Forms](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms)

> ```
> Form                           Description
> ——————————————————————————————————————————
> Normalization Form D (NFD)     Canonical Decomposition
> Normalization Form C (NFC)     Canonical Decomposition,
>                                followed by Canonical Composition
> Normalization Form KD (NFKD)   Compatibility Decomposition
> Normalization Form KC (NFKC)   Compatibility Decomposition,
>                                followed by Canonical Composition
> ```